# Overriding plugin functions from a theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

There is a plugin that has all of its presentation functions declared so that they can be overriden.  I.e.:

```
if (!function_exists('show_thing')){ ... }
```

How should this be done?  I tried declaring the function in my themes functions.php but it was already declared by that point of execution.

If I create my own plugin with the method declarations then how can I ensure my plugin loads before this plugin does and functions are definitely overriden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use a [Must Use Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins). Create a folder called `/wp-content/mu-plugins`. Any PHP file in this directory will be loaded (they do not have to be activated) and will be executed before the activated plugins or your theme files (including `functions.php`). Use a file here to define the functions that you want to override from the plugin.

Check out this diagram for more info on the WP Core load order: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26622/20880

Comment: For extra credit: if you want to be able to enable and disable the functionality you can use a custom plugin and then and make sure it is included first by setting its position in the "active_plugins" array. You can see an example here: http://justinsilver.com/technology/wordpress/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-plugin-custom-functions-php/